# Как получить первый дочерний элемент, в котором сработало событие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

как при наведении мышки на TD, получить `<div id=".">` (  первый дочерний элемент родителя `<div id="body_infoReg">` в котором сработало событие ). надеюсь правильно объяснил =) спасибо

```js
// При нажатии на td (кроме перв
$('#body_infoReg').on('mouseover', 'table tr:not(:first-child) td:first-child', function() {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body_infoReg">

  <div id="1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <div id="2">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: попробуйте `elem.firstElementChild`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать метод `.parentsUntil()`

```js
$('td').on('mouseover', function() {
  console.log($(this).parentsUntil('#body_infoReg').last().attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body_infoReg">

  <div id="1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1.3</td>
        <td>1.4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="2">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>2.1</td>
        <td>2.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2.3</td>
        <td>2.4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Несколько пояснений к вашей и исправленной разметке. Если вы хотите поместить данные в `dom` объект, не нужно выдумывать для этого новый ТЕГ (id="1"), правильней поместить данные в `data-` с желаемым названием, вот так - `data-id="2"`.

Если вы хотите обратиться к конкретному родителю, задайте ему класс (к примеру `<div class="table-block" data-id="1">`)

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '#body_infoReg td', function() {
  console.log($(this).parents('.table-block').data('id'));
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="body_infoReg">
  <div class="table-block" data-id="1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="table-block" data-id="2">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#body_infoReg').on('mouseover', 'table tr:not(:first-child) td:first-child', function() {
   var divParent = $(this).closest('div[id]');
});
```